# Can this all be done in php and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to do the following but I want to find out if its possible and whats the easiest way to do it before I spend hours looking on google for something that isn't possible. The situation is a web app that would run of a users localhost so they can configure a config.php file.

1. Can the number of available check boxes be set in a config.php file.  ie.

   `$numberofcheckboxes ="4"`
2. Can descriptions be set for these in the config.php ie.
3. When these check boxes are displayed and ticked and then submitted can a php function be run with variables depending on which checkboxes were ticked. So in the config.php you would set the different variables for each checkbox. ie.

   `$check1name = "name 1"`
   `$check1size ="120"`

   `$check2name ="name 2"`
   `$check2size ="160"`

The function is always exactly the same function however the variables will be different for each checkbox.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, all of that can be done in php and javascript/jquery.

Comment: Yes, but don't use spaces in the names use underscores.

Comment: Wait - what do you mean by "Run off a users localhost"?

Comment: Run on there pc.. Like not online.. If it was online they wouldn't have control over config.php directly. Thanks guys :)

Comment: If you want to run PHP on their machine, then they will need to have PHP and a Web Server installed locally.

Comment: Yes I know. The users will :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand your final aim, but the ideas you describe sound feasible to me. However, I'd recommend defining the checkboxes and their details using an associative array, instead of as individual variables. Then you can use `count($checkbox_array)` to see how many checkboxes there are, and reference certain values using the number of the checkbox, like `$checkbox_array[0]['name']`.

Also, be aware of the difference between strings and integers. `$numberofcheckboxes="4";` assigns a string, whereas `$numberofcheckboxes=4;` assigns an integer. Because PHP is loosely-typed you might not notice the difference in this case, but it is nonetheless an important difference to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. New to php and only being using variables. Will learn about arrays before I set out to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use jquery...
Give your checkbox the same class, something like "chkclass". And give the value of checkbox in the value property. Then you can make a function that runs every click. Look at this code.

```
$(".chkclass").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        //add your code here
        //if you want to call some php with ajax, you can use .load function from jquery
    }
});
```

I wish this is what you're talking about.. :)